# Can someone show me how to populate a list of lists in haskell from a textfile or a csv file?

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and am performing matrix multiplication.
I want to populate a list of list from a text file and a csv file in haskell.
So for example my text file or csv contains

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9

please ignore the blank lines between rows in text file.

I want my lists of list to be `matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: based on the example `lines` and `words` should help you (you'll probably want `read`  to get numbers as well)

Answer (score 2):

```
Prelude> mdata <- readFile("matrix.data")
Prelude> (map (map read . words) . lines) mdata :: [[Int]]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```